# ITfFnReconversion::QueryRange outputs NULL with "Microsoft IME(Japanese)"

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, text-services-framework

Referencing the article of [Get the candicate list by TSF](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA050396/tech_01.html)(sorry, it's written by Japanese), I have developed a C++ Component of **Windows Store App**.
But when I test the Component, there is a curious phenomenon: If I turn the Input Method into "Microsoft IME", the code

```
hr = m_reconversion_cp->QueryRange(selections[0].range, &range_cp, &is_converted);
```

always returns NULL in the output param "range_cp", but if I turn the Input Method into "Google 日本語入力"  the "range_cp" will return right result and I can get the candidate List by ITfFnReconversion::GetReconversion.
Has someone encountered the same issue? Or I missed some settings of the Microsoft IME?

There is the part of code of this issue:

```
ReconvTextStore m_text_store_cp;
ITfContext m_context_cp;
ITfFnReconversion m_reconversion_cp

if (m_text_store_cp->LockDocument(TS_LF_READ))
{
    hr = m_context_cp->GetSelection(
        m_edit_cookie,
        TF_DEFAULT_SELECTION,
        numberof(selections),
        selections,
        &fetched_count
        );

    m_text_store_cp->UnlockDocument();

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        break;
    }
}

// ↓↓↓ When the Microsoft IME, range_cp returns NULL　↓↓↓
hr = m_reconversion_cp->QueryRange(selections[0].range, &range_cp, &is_converted);
if (FAILED(hr) || range_cp == NULL)
{
    break;
}

hr = m_reconversion_cp->GetReconversion(selections[0].range, &cand_list_cp);
if (FAILED(hr) || cand_list_cp == NULL)
{
    break;
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you insert the text in question using the Microsoft IME?  TSF tracks the "owner" (text service that inserted the text) and doesn't allow reconversion requests for text that you didn't insert.

Comment: @EricBrown  First, thanks for your answer, especial for the keyword "owner", I am looking up some information about it. And about your question, No, I just handled the word in the textbox by the virtual keyboard in my applications instead of the real keyboard. But by the same source, the Google Japanese input method can reconver normally, so the Microsoft IME uses a different interface, or should I handle the "owner"?

Comment: How does the virtual keyboard in your application insert text?

Comment: In any case, try inserting the text with the Microsoft IME and see if it works.   If it works when the text is inserted with the Microsoft IME, then it's likely that the Microsoft IME is adding metadata (what TSF calls properties) that the Microsoft IME is using for reconversion.   If the Google IME reconverts where the Microsoft IME does not, then it's likely that the Google IME has a different reconversion algorithm that doesn't need extra metadata.

Comment: @EricBrown thanks for your response again.  I renewed a application and referenced the component which the issue occured. This time I gave up the virtual keyboard and used the physical keyboard to input the words, but unfortunately the issue remained.

Comment: I did a brief check on the Microsoft IME sources, and the query range can fail if there's a composition active, as well as some other conditions that I haven't had a chance to fully understand.